# Is returning a more specific type a good use case for hiding base class properties?

Tags: c#

In a project I'm currently maintaining we have a core base class which has a property for a kind of context object:

```
public abstract class Base
{
  public BaseContext Context { get; protected set; }
}
```

Usually if `Base` is derived, `BaseContext` needs to be derived as well, and you usually need the more specific context in the derived class. So I thought the following might be pretty nice to have:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
  public new DerivedContext Context
  {
    get { return (DerivedContext) base.Context; }
    protected set { base.Context = value; }
  }
}
```

From a type safety perspective this should all be fine, except the cast, which, shouldn't fail however, since the class can only set the property itself. Using this cuts a few casts in the code where I otherwise have `((DerivedContext) Context).Foo` in a few cases where I actually need properties/methods of the derived context.

Is there any red flag that would speak against such shadowing?

(Thinking about it again, there probably is another way, using generics, to achieve the same:

```
public abstract class Base<TContext> where TContext : BaseContext
{
  public TContext Context { get; protected set; }
}

public class Derived : Base<DerivedContext> {}
```

which doesn't require hiding the base member. Might overall be cleaner, maybe.)

Answer (score 4):

Shadowing is often a bad idea in general. And it doesn't seem like it's necessary here either - why not use a generic class?

```
public abstract class Base<T>
{
  public T Context { get; protected set; }
}

public class Derived : Base<DerivedContext>
{
  ...
}
```

No casting, no shadowing, all strongly typed.

Comment: Oh great, the instant I come up with that idea and write it as an edit to the question an answer appears suggesting the same ;-)

Comment: Optionally add a generic constraint for T to be of type BaseContext.

Comment: There is a duplicate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567957/design-to-avoid-type-casting-in-derived-classes which has a similar answer.

Comment: @openshac: Vote to close is a valid option in that case. I searched, but that's a tricky question to search for.

Comment: I think making that abstract class a generic is not a good idea, because you can't have an instance of base class without knowing about its type parameters. It will harden using of it in more base tiers.

Comment: @alisabzevari, you cannot have an instance of an abstract class in any case or am I missing anything? And with the generic constraint `TContext` is at least a `BaseContext` anyway so you wouldn't need to know the specific type parameters, no? Or am I missing something right now?

Comment: @alisabzevari You're never making an instance of `Base<T>` directly - you'll always have a concrete type with no (visible) generic arguments (e.g. you're calling `new Derived()`, not `new Base<DerivedContext>`). If you need a less-specific way of handling this, you can always use interfaces *in addition* to the generic classes.

Comment: @Joey: I don't mean instantiating. Assume you have a method that gives an instance of ˋBaseˋ as a parameter. You have to declare its type as Base<BaseContext> or something else. If you don't think about covariance and contravariance of this class it make working with that type very hard.

Comment: @alisabzevari Yeah, that's exactly why you'd use an interface, really. Explicit implementation of the interface will also take care of hiding the "less-specific" methods, not to mention that it will give you better control over what you're actually trying to do.